# not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate, but triggers on update (postgresql 9.3)

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I create a very simple function, ensuring it only happens with an update.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION simple_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
        _unused_variable INTEGER; -- unrelated placeholder.
BEGIN
        IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
                INSERT INTO trigger_log(id, value) values (OLD.id, OLD.value);
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I register the trigger

```
DROP TRIGGER simple_trigger_trigger on trigger_test; -- just in case. 
CREATE TRIGGER simple_trigger_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON trigger_test FOR EACH statement execute procedure simple_trigger();
```

I have simple table being inserted into on update.

```
mydatabase=# \d trigger_log
  Table "public.trigger_log"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 id     | integer | 
 value  | integer |
```

Nothing in that table at first.

```
mydatabase=# select * from trigger_log;
 id | value 
----+-------
(0 rows)
```

Three rows in `trigger_test` (the table being updated).

```
mydatabase=# select * from trigger_test;
 id | value 
----+-------
  1 |     2   
  2 |     2   
  3 |     2   
(3 rows)
```

I can't update and have the insert happen.

```
mydatabase=# update trigger_test set value = 100 where id = 2;
ERROR:  record "old" is not assigned yet 
DETAIL:  The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO trigger_log(id, value) values (OLD.id, OLD.value)"
PL/pgSQL function simple_trigger() line 6 at SQL statement
```

My understanding per [postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/plpgsql-trigger.html) was that `NEW` is unassigned on `DELETE` operations and `OLD` is unassigned on `INSERT` operations. That makes sense. This is neither.

**How can it possible be unassigned?**

This is very frustrating. I can't think of a more simple example.

Answer (score 2):

My mistake. Trigger was for each statement; should have been for each row.

```
CREATE TRIGGER simple_trigger_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON trigger_test 
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE simple_trigger();
```

Comment: I have made the same mistake many times too.